# Why don't we get reputation for upvotes on comments?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments)

Some of the comments are really helpful in answering the questions. At times people edit their answers to include the changes as per the comments. So why should upvotes on comments not boost one's rep?

Are we coming up with the feature of adding comment votes to rep?

Thanks :)

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments

Answer (score 15):

If they awarded rep for comments, my snarky, pony-referencing comments would ensure that I hit my rep limit every day. Even I don't think that I deserve to get rep for all of my smart-ass comments.

Comment: Upvoted for being the truest thing I've read all week.

Comment: But how about having 1 reputation for 1 vote or 5 or 10. I think there should be something, because I edited an answer based on someone's comments and got 2 votes in addition to the 2 given before the edit.

Comment: Nevermind I agree with `Earwicker's` answer below.

Answer (score 10):

If upvotes on comments were "valuable", I think you'd need to add downvotes on comments and make the downvotes have negative value, because otherwise they'd skew people's rep misleadingly.

And the result would merely be amplification of rep based on whether people had posted comments under their own answers or not. You'd see an explosion of use of the comments system for things that had previously gone into answers, probably making the answers less readable. Then people would want code snippets to work in comments.

I think the votes against comments are not about rep. They're just a quick way for someone else to say "I would have said the same thing" without having to type it out. If someone disagrees, they can write a comment of their own saying why.

Answer (score 3):

I like the fact theres no rep for comments. Sometimes comments can be used to make remarks that aren't necessarily relevant but are either insightful or just amusing. Now I don't mind that because there's not too much of it to just be annoying. Incentivising it would create more of it. We don't need that.

Comment: Agreed. In my experience most of the top upvoted comments have been upvoted because they are funny. Nothing wrong with that, of course, but your ability to make funny one-liners shouldn't be what makes your reputation, in my opinion.