# Is there any benefit when a user improves (edits) a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, edits

If a user (other than the OP) edits a question and makes it significantly more understandable or better formatted for consumption (reading) is there anyway to reward that user with some rep?

Comment: you could go to one of their other questions or answers and do that, but you can't vote up the user that edited the question as it relates to the question that was edited. right?

Comment: I'm talking about if someone other than the OP does the edit.

Answer (score 7):

Just karma. It's a good thing to do, but there's no actual rep benefit etc (other than the editor badge).

There have been proposals for voting on edits, but I don't personally see the need, beyond the ability to perhaps flag a particular edit as offensive.

Comment: Agree. Adding a separate voting ability would be too complicated for users.

Comment: Valid points.  I think there are a lot of questions by non-english speakers or people in a hurry that are valid but benefit greatly from some editing.  Sometimes a bit of editing is the difference between a question getting a meaningful answer and getting down voted away.  Maybe if there were some reward possible for editing one of these questions more people would do it resulting in less first time users having a bad experience because they didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: I agree too, it's a bit like rep for comments (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments), KISS.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to their profile page, find an answer or question and upvote it.

Keep in mind, I **do not** advocate this on an arbitrary question. I just think that you'll find if you like the way the person edits, then chances are you will also easily be able to find a very strong answer that they authored all the way through.

The other bonus is that if the question is interesting, you might learn something by reading all the responses on it, and you might end up upvoting a lot of the answers.

The downside is that you might stumble across an answer by that person that you end up downvoting, so they'll be worse off... whoops.

But in general, anyone who is a good editor, will tend to get a lot of upvotes on their questions/answers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's a badge you earn once after a certain number of edits, but that's it.