# Give reputation points for "significant" edits

Tags: feature-request, reputation, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Reputation points for editing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41757/reputation-points-for-editing)

I was thinking about how Stack Overflow (and sibling sites) could support reputation points for providing edits to other users posts.  I was thinking some combination of the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), percentage of content change, and time since last edit (e.g. encourage others to come back and edit some time *after* the post "cools down").  This way users who provide, hopefully, good edits for the benefit of the community can share in earning reputation points if the revised post is voted up.

Thoughts?

**Update**

I think everyone is focusing on the suggestion for earning reputation points for edits, and not on the *approach* that may (or may not) be new.  I understand others have suggested adding the ability to earn reputation points on edits - not a new suggestion.  What I think is a new suggestion is how one might determine if an edit *sufficiently adds value* and is therefore *worthy* of earning reputation.  Could someone re-open this question and offer comments/answers on that part of the suggestion?  Thanks!

#### See also:

> - [Is there any benefit when a user improves (edits) a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8875/is-there-any-benefit-when-a-user-improves-edits-a-question)
> - [Reputation points for editing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41757/reputation-points-for-editing)
> - [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer)
> - [Adding incentive for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278/adding-incentive-for-editing)

Comment: Related is the new dupe

Answer (score 3):

There's one clear advantage to this idea, and two great big disadvantages...

It *would* be nice if, when users repeatedly post lazy questions that need heavy editing, they got only a fraction of the reputation granted after the edits. I should say, this would be nice if it actually motivated them to take a bit more time on their questions in the future... It's a bit frustrating to see users with thousands of rep points on SO still posting questions where the language they're asking about is misspelled in the title.

However as nice as that sounds, it would add a huge opportunity for abuse on the site: just edit a popular post and skim off a bit of rep by doing so, even if there's no real need for the edit.

And worse yet... It would replace the current motivation for editing (an intrinsic desire to see better posts on SO) with an external motivator. This doesn't *necessarily* mean that the people who edit now would leave and be replaced by rep-hungry butchers, but it sure sets the stage for such displacement.

Comment: I've seen `C` misspelled in the tile - very sad :(