# Rep for good edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let me reward a good edit on my question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36574/let-me-reward-a-good-edit-on-my-question-answer)

I think users should be able to vote on edits to questions so that people can gain (or lose) rep for good edits to questions.

Good edits can take time (especially on poorly phrased questions) and users should have an incentive to do so, aside from just having a better site. (The argument could be made for asking good questions as well: Why should I care how my question is phrased/formatted etc so long as I get the answer?)

Your thoughts?

Comment: This question is different than the other. I'm asking about voting on edits to *other* people's questions.

Comment: You get a reopen vote from me :)

Comment: This may not be a dupe of the question random closed with, but it is a dupe. [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42051/give-reputation-points-for-significant-edits) covers it _and_ provides an algorithm. Pretty sure there are others too.