# What benefit does a user get for editing posts?

Tags: discussion, edits

What is the benefit for the user who edits an answer in order to improve some of its aspects?

Does he get any reputation points when the answer is upvoted?

Comment: Only when that editor has less than 2000 rep. See ["How do suggested edits work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work). Otherwise it's only for the benefit of the site.

Comment: The benefit is to have a better answer for next people entering in the site.

Comment: And how much does we get for 1 up-vote?

Comment: 10 rep for an answer, 5 for a question. Unless you mean the editor. In that case, he gets none.

Comment: Worth to mention is [was already suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82425/152859) for editors to get reputation when the post is upvoted.

Comment: @sha-wiz-dow-ard Someone has edited this question, will he get some points when this question is up-voted?

Comment: @asim-ishaq: No. Only the OP will get any reputation change from votes (either up or down).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a user doesn't have edit privileges yet and the suggested edit is accepted, the user will gain +2 reputation for the edit. There will be no reputation gains from upvotes on the post.

There are also badges awarded for edits - the [Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor), [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) and [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/65/copy-editor).

The general benefit is that an answer was made better for *everyone* who reads it.

Comment: Don't forget badges.