# Do you get points for upvoted comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, up-votes

Do you get points/reputation for upvoted comments?

I know this is a question I should be able to find easily, but I can't seem to find it by searching here or skimming the FAQ.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[No:](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/16/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/)

> No reputation of any kind is earned or lost from comment votes.

There is, however, [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments is a better link.

Answer (score 18):

#### 4 easy steps to become a pundit:

1. Camp out on “fun” questions (but only comment on them).
2. Be mildly amusing.
3. ???
4. Pundit!

Uh, wait. A pundit is someone who makes bad puns, right?

Comment: Wikied because a) it doesn't answer the question, b) I already posted it as a comment to the blog, and c) it was so bad then that I had to slap myself after I posted it.

Comment: I completely agree with your comment! keep up the good work

Comment: You mean I should keep slapping myself? *(Ow!)*

Comment: `>Uh, wait. A pundit is someone who makes bad puns, right?` - No, that’s a pun *twit*.

Comment: This is a fine meta-answer-comment-combo by mmyers: Stating a hypothesis in the answer and proving it right with the comment ;)

Comment: But it adds on to @Shog9 's answer on how to get the badge.

Comment: I keep slapping myself but I don't feel any more wise. What part did I miss?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no. Your reputation will not be changed because of comment votes. But you must earn enough reputation to be able to comment.

Comment: This does not add anything relevant not already present in existing answers.