# Flagging a comment which was upvoted

Tags: support, comments, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it)

I was about to ask how do I undo an upvoted comment, but then I [saw this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/do-you-get-points-for-upvoted-comments), so coming to part 2, I accidentally upvoted a comment (instead of flagging it), so now how do I flag the comment? Flag the whole post and say please check comment X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would work. I doubt it is worth doing much more...