# Comment upvote and flag links are too close

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Today I wanted to flag a comment as offensive, but accidentally upvoted it instead. And as if that wasn't bad enough, now I can't flag it anymore.

I suppose the logic makes sense.

*"Why would someone want to flag a comment they liked?"*

Well, *"because they clicked upvote by mistake because flag & upvote are too damn close, that's why!"*

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/frsEH.jpg]

<sub><sup>I still can't understand why upvoting a comment shouldn't be reversible for a few seconds…</sup></sub>

Comment: (And as for your small print: see [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment))

Comment: (See also [Flagging a comment which was upvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/flagging-a-comment-which-was-upvoted), which it NOT tagged `feature-request` though!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now fixed, you can "unupvote" your comment and then flag it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading waffle's [other answer to a similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/157163) which states how the new feature works.