# Can't flag comment after accidental upvote

Tags: feature-request, flags, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow flagging a Comment after voting it up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-voting-it-up)

inb4 duplicate of: [Comment upvote and flag links are too close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45368/upvote-comment-and-flag-comment-to-close)

However that question doesn't address the problem of an accidental upvote leading to being unable to flag a comment.  Instead it merely agrees with the logic of not being able to report something you supported and leaves it at that.

Constructive...

Whilst I agree with the logic of not needing to flag a comment you've upvoted, I would like to re-introduce what that question (and several others) fail to address, which is the desire to correct the inability to flag a comment after accidentally upvoting it.  This happened to me moments ago, and I'm surprised that I'm not finding more support for this.

That being said, I would like to do what other questions failed, and formerly request a process to flag a comment that has been accidentally upvoted (be it via undoing an upvote or what have you).

If said process exists, how does one go about reconciling this?