# Remove upvote on a comment that's been edited

Tags: feature-request, comment-voting, comment-edits

There's been a bunch of question regarding removing upvotes on comments (most of them accidental), most of which, if not all, has been closed as duplicates. However, I feel this is different.

I upvoted a comment a while back, and didn't think much of it (it was a good comment). I come back a while later, only to notice that I've upvoted a rather strange comment. After a few seconds I notice the 'edited' icon, and realize the comment has been completely rewritten, in a tone that I don't want to condone at all.

Now I can't remove the upvote. Perhaps we'd need the same thing as for other votes, and after the corresponding entry has been edited you're free to change your vote (or even flag?).

Comment: Yes, I agree this would be a good feature. I upvoted a comment that answered [my question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58340/lets-not-sweat-it#comment110756_58340) so I upvoted but suddenly the user removed its answer from it, and his comment was only a harsh response. I want to remove the upvote but I can't!

Answer (score 4):

Unlike posts, the editing window for comments is only the first 5 minutes after the comment is posted, and it can *only* be edited by the owner.

(moderators are of course the exception here.. if it's a moderator comment being edited then flag the post and explain why you are uncomfortable with the edit.)

I don't expect comment rewrite editing to happen with enough frequency to justify a whole bunch of extra code to undo comment votes.

Comment: and yet this would also solve the trouble of [accidental up-votes which were intended as flagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/flagging-a-comment-which-was-upvoted) without requiring moderator intervention...

Comment: I definately see your point, incidentally, I had the same concern. But then I thought, since it's already implemented, depending on your architecture, it might not be a "whole bunch of extra code". But you know that better than I do. Thanks for the answer.