# Seeking ability to flag upvoted comment as obsolete

Tags: feature-request, comment-voting, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow flagging a Comment after voting it up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-voting-it-up)

Once you've upvoted a comment, it's impossible for you flag it.

It should be possible to flag it as obsolete: a comment can be upvoteworthy at first but obsolete in light of later edits or comments.