# Flagging should not be removed from comments that you have upvoted

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it)

The Scenario (which happened to me today)

1. User posts a comment to an answer "Hey, your answer is 100% incorrect"
2. I agree, so I upvote comment
3. Answer is edited to be 100% correct by somebody
4. The "Hey, your answer is 100% incorrect" comment is no longer constructive, nor relevant

It feels like serious overkill removing the flagging functionality from comments that you have upvoted.

Comment: What happens if you undo your upvote? Are you allowed to flag, then?

Comment: @J.Steen - If we undo our upvote on comment, we are allowed to flag. But we can undo our upvote on comment within a minute.

Comment: @hims056 Ah. I wasn't aware of the time constraint. I've never wanted to undo my upvote after a minute before. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/187824 :)

Comment: @hims056 Thanks! I was just searching for such information. I'm really starting to understand why there are so very many duplicates on meta...

Comment: @J.Steen - Actually some people don't search for duplicate before asking a question and some people search but can't find it so they ask duplicate...

Comment: @hims056 Of course. Just saying, there *seems* to be an unusually high level of duplicates on specifically meta. But, that's neither here nor there and certainly not on-topic for this question. =D

Comment: It's not that I didn't search for a duplicate, it's that I did not find the duplicate. I always make an effort.