# Why was question flag declined when requested action was taken?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, declined-flags

I found a few other related questions, but they were in regards to flags for different reasons such as closing the question.

I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22110460/1862009) to say that all comments were obsolete. I would have flagged the comments individually, but there were several and one of them was one I had upvoted. I wasn't able to flag that one. Though, I have since found a [solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216147/203410) for flagging upvoted comments.

The flag was declined but all comments are gone. I suppose it's possible that the two authors deleted their own comments, but I don't think that is likely.

So why was it declined? I'm wondering if this was an accident or if I was wrong to flag the question. If the latter, please explain why.

Comment: Perhaps someone *else* used a different flag on the same posts; if that flag is wrong the moderators have no other option but to decline *all* flags.

Comment: Anyways, I don’t know why. It’s not because there were multiple flags on the question. (There was another, but it was declined March 1st.) I’ll go ask =)

Comment: @toxalot Nevermind then.  Your explanation of how to go about easily mass-flagging gave me the false impression that that's what you actually did.

Comment: @Servy I actually did think it was better to flag comments individually than to flag the question for moderator attention. Comment flags seem to get handled faster so I thought they were handled at a lower level. I thought it would annoy mods to flag a question for attention if it could have been easily handled at a lower level.

Comment: @toxalot They go to different queues, but both queues are mod-only queues.

Comment: @Servy So to clarify, it's better to flag *question* for attention than *individual comments* when requesting mass deletion of comments?

Comment: Depends whether you have something else to say. I might actually recommend you used an Other comment flag, though, since our Other general flag queue continues to be the longest, and it’s applicable to comments.

Comment: @toxalot You could, or you could just *flag one of the comments* and explain in the comment flag that the whole comment thread should be looked at.  Which queue you want to send it to is really up to you, the point though is that you should send one flag either way, not a whole slew of flags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was the moderator who processed the flag and when I reviewed *I saw 2 flags on it*:

- your "Other" flag to review/delete the obsolete comments
- a flag that was urging the moderators to help with the question because it was urgent

We only have the ability to mark all flags as helpful or declined.  In my review, I missed that the second flag was previously declined so I declined the flags. This was obviously an oversight on my part, your flag was correct.

My suggestion would be to use the "Other" comment flag because they will go into the comment flag queue instead of the main queue.

Comment: Hell of a way to start your modship there bluefeet. You're already apologizing? What horrors doth the future hold?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Well I made a mistake, I'll own that.

Comment: (Also, if it's not obvious I'm just teasing.)

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to know why. And I'll use the *Other* comment flag from now on instead. You ruined my perfect flag score, though. :) Just teasing.