# Flagging upvoted comment is not possible in iOS App

Tags: support, bug, comments, ios-app

I tried to flag a previously upvoted comment in the *iOS App* and I couldn't find the option to **Flag**. I then checked on other comments and on different SE-communities.

Here is what I observed everytime:

- As soon as I tap **Upvote**, the button **Flag** disappears:
  [image: upvoted]
- When I tap **Undo Upvote**, the button appears again:
  [image: normal]

I was able to flag the comment normally on the website itself, so it must be a bug in the iOS App.
Or is this intended behavior? If yes, how do I flag an upvoted comment using the iOS App?

Comment: The web interface doesn't allow you to flag a comment you upvoted, either, but there's a userscript out there that puts it back.  Is it possible you're using that script in your browser?  (I agree that you should be able to flag a previously-upvoted comment, for example one that has become obsolete.)

Comment: @Monica The web interface [allows to flag a comment that I upvoted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hXBty.png) without any scripts/hacks.

Comment: Oh, nice to know!  That didn't always work.  I assumed I was getting it from SOUP, but didn't go digging.

Comment: @Monica that was the case indeed until [two years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236522/152859).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed in the latest bugfix release (version 1.5.3) as stated in the description of the update:

> - Allowed flagging comment you previously upvoted.

Now, when you tap **Upvote**, the **Flag** button is still available:
[image: screenshot showing option to flag when comment is upvoted]

Consequently, flagging previously upvoted comments using the iOS App is possible from now on.