# Can't flag an up voted comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I often flag comments as obsolete after i.e. the suggestion has been added to the question/answer -- or for any reason that fits into 'obsolete'.

Sometimes I revisit a question from days ago and I can't flag the comments I've up voted. Which forces me to hop on my laptop and do it from the desktop site (you can flag up voted comments on the desktop site) -- that is if I'm feeling really persistent about it.

Can this functionality be added to the iOS app?

Comment: Feel free to test it

Comment: Just log into your sockpuppet to flag it.

Comment: @John Because that's not a hassle ;)

Comment: This is 100% an API issue.  I'm just finishing up some app changes then I'll switch to Windows to have a look at it.

Comment: Funny how people keep down voting this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just kidding, it's a UI bug and will be fixed in 1.5.3.4.

When the app was first released in April(?) 2014, you couldn't flag a comment you upvoted.  A few month's later, [that feature was added to the web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236522/235711) and I completely missed it.  Well, we're getting it now!