# reputation for good comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you get points for upvoted comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/do-you-get-points-for-upvoted-comments)

Is any reputation gained from having your comments upvoted?  I thought I saw somewhere that they were but it doesn't seem to happen.  If this is not the case, why not?  I seems like getting a little rep for comments would be appropriate.  Some of them deserve it.

Comment: You don't earn reputation for comments. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments

Comment: Dupe of, among others, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/do-you-get-points-for-upvoted-comments.

Answer (score 5):

Nope.  There is a Pundit badge for leaving 10 comments with score of 10 or more.  Comments seem to get upvoted based more on humor than on value to the OP.  This would be one reason why I wouldn't be in favor of giving rep for comment upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think if a comment helps answer a question, then it ought to have been proposed as an answer to the question – perhaps qualified as a partial answer, or "I agree with so and so, **except** ..."

Comments are just fine as-is.  The extra badges for popular comments are cool though.