# Why do comment upvotes not give rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reputation for good comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33072/reputation-for-good-comments)

Why are users not rewarded for posting good comments? The stack overflow team must have considered this, so I was just wondering the reason why it isn't the case.

Edit: If it doesn't give you rep, why does the comment upvote feature exist?

Comment: This is ***NOT*** a duplicate.  It does ***NOT*** ask *if* comments get rep, but *why they do not*.  Anyone who can't see the difference should have moderator status revoked.

Comment: True.  It is, though, a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments

Comment: upvoted because this Q&A gets straight to the crux. also, even if it is a duplicate, it obviously wasn't deliberate and -1 is all that's needed to stop people looking at a question (no need for -7)

Answer (score 8):

Reputation is gained for questions and answers which are what Stack Exchange sites are all about.

Comments, on the other hand, are not the main focus of the site so rewarding them would bring in unwanted behaviour (people spamming posts with comments in order to gain rep).

Comment: Why does the comment up-vote feature exist then?

Comment: @CameronMartin - To show that a comment was agreed with. Comments are not answers and shouldn't be treated as answers.