# How many points do I get if my comment gets an upvote?

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you get points for upvoted comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/do-you-get-points-for-upvoted-comments)

How many points do I get if my comment gets an upvote? Sorry if it's a duplicate/dumb question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

none.. but I think there is badge based on comment 'votes'

see: the [Pundit Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit) awarded for:

> Left 10 comments with score of 5 or
>   more.

and [Commentator Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator) awarded for

> Left 10 comments.

Answer (score 8):

None whatsoever. It can become more visible if there are too many comments to display.