# Does comment up-vote affect reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you get points for upvoted comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/do-you-get-points-for-upvoted-comments)

Does a comment up-vote result in an increase in the commenter's reputation?

Comment: or [Reputation for comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments) Also [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/148672) enumerates all the ways you can get or lose reputation