# What is the highest upvoted comment on the Trilogy?

Tags: comments, data-dump, discussion

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake/686342#686342) has a comment by Pesto  which right now is at +91. I am curious as to whether or not there is anything higher than +91 in terms of comments on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think Pesto's comment would have gotten even more votes if it wasn't added to the answer.

Comment: Pesto's comment is the only reason that answer got voted up as high as it did.

Comment: @TheTXI - Agreed.

Comment: @yshuditelu If it wasn't added to the answer, the comment wouldn't have existed, hence it would have 0 upvotes.

Comment: @Daniel: He meant if it wasn't edited into the actual text of the answer.

Comment: @gnovice: Oh! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Here is a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/47) that searches for the highest-scoring comments on a given site. Since it's SEDE, it ignores deleted comments (including comments on deleted posts) and may be up to two months out-of-date.

As things stand (Sep. 2011), the [top voted comment on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353436) with a score of 1215 is:

> "sigh . . ...... :<" -Jimmy

[On SU](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for), with a score of 328:

> "Knowing the answer makes me feel so old..." –Joe

[On SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants), with a score of 190:

> "You have two weeks to deliver him the information, and it takes two weeks to move to somewhere else who can process credit cards. Don't bother - make the decision to move now and abandon the audit." –Scrivener

[On Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134), with a score of 353:

> "Who the hell is Jon Skeet?" –thenduks

Comment: Missing this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133581/is-23-148-855-308-184-500-a-magic-number-or-sheer-chance/1133612#1133612

Comment: The double-negative of "not non-wiki" is a bit odd..

Comment: *blink* Oh, wow.  The #3 non-wiki-comment is mine.  I had no idea!  It's also got about 4 times as many votes as my best answer :-/

Comment: For fun, go over statoverflow.com/sandbox and add a where clause condition to limit it to your user id.

Comment: Wow, just realized I had one in the 80's. Forgot I even made that comment.

Comment: eh haha, I can recognize the comment from the legendary SF question

Answer (score 1):

[Who the hell is Jon Skeet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) – thenduks Apr 21 at 20:37 is currently at 206.

Comment: If there had been comment voting when you asked that question, I'll bet there would have been several comments with 500 votes.

Answer (score 1):

[The top 100 comments on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/113022/best-comments).

Answer (score 0):

I know there are several with over 100 votes. Besides [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895296/how-can-you-tell-if-a-person-is-a-programmer/895403#895403) (currently at 135 votes), there's [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/184673#184673) (currently at 148) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) (currently at 213).

Comment: The other two comments aren't funny, though. Mine's really the only one worth looking at, in my completely unbiased opinion.

Comment: That question actually got me about halfway to the badge-that-shall-not-be-named. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888224/what-is-your-longest-held-programming-assumption-that-turned-out-to-be-incorrect did the rest, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378#comment-2328409) and pushed it to 750:

> sigh . . ...... :< – Jimmy ↵ Mar 1 at 6:30

Comment: That one was a great combination of timing, restraint, and being in the right place at the right time.