# Should usernames in all capital letters be allowed?

Tags: discussion

Consider a theoretical username of "FOR EXCEPTIONALLY GREAT JUSTICE".

Is it appropriate for a username to 'shout'?  If not, should "no all caps usernames" be an enforceable rule, a guideline, or neither?

Comment: What about ראובן as username? I don't even know if he is insulting me! :D

Comment: It's those all lower case names that get to me.

Comment: @belisarius ベレアー アダム is japanese for Adam Belleaire, source: google translate :D I though it would be funnier!

Comment: Are the downvotes here against all-caps usernames, or against the proposed "no all-caps usernames" rule?

Comment: @Popular yes (2 more to go)

Comment: Please comment if you've down voted the question.  I'd like to provide better questions in the future.  If you dislike the rule, please up vote one of the many answers that agree with your position or provide one of your own.

Comment: @Thomas: that's a bit different on meta. Downvote == disagreement. It's not that Downvote == bad question like as on SO. In contrary :)

Comment: @BalusC That's not in the FAQ.  Where can I go learn more meta specific customs?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-people-downvoting-my-question-on-meta and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20676/why-do-people-take-downvoting-on-meta-so-personally. To learn more about meta, check the tag combo `[discussion][meta]`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+meta

Answer (score 7):

There's already a length restriction, so I don't have a problem with ALL CAPS user names.  A short user name shouting at me is a lot less annoying than a title or a full post body.

On top of that, you're allowed to name your SO account after your blog or company if you want to.  If your trademark is in all caps (as annoying as that may be), you'll want to carry that over.

Comment: I certainly hope you wouldn't have a problem with [ALL CAPS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/all-caps) ♪

Comment: @Grace: I hadn't seen that yet.  His profile is always entertaining.  :)

Comment: there even is a chat room http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/328/all-caps-room

Comment: There's a length restriction? Whose idea was that, Zypher's? ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think it should be at most a suggestion. It's my name, let me choose whatever I want.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be allowed for the following reasons:

1. Some names need all uppercase
2. If someone has a user name that is all upper case it doesn't hurt readability in the same manner as reading a paragraph of uppercase text.
3. Uppercase lettering in a post might be seen as shouting but in a name I don't think it really matters.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not introduce "coding guidelines" to usernames. One man's meat is another's poison, etc. A lot of these things are a subjective personal experience, so you can't please everyone.