# Earn Reputation For Comments

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments)

Hello,

I suggesting to so a system that if your comments are up voted you earn some reputation, something like 1 point for each up vote or 1 point per 3 up votes(or something like this). Thanks.

Comment: Can I vote to close as, "The horse is already dead." ??

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments

Answer (score 3):

Up to a point, a good idea.  The rate should probably not be 1 rep point per up vote but smaller (hence 1 rep point per 3 up votes).  There should probably also be a way to undo upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I like this in the sense that comments are still a "contribution to the community".

However, they certainly don't hold nearly the same value as actual answers, so you'd have to choose your point value wisely. Don't want rep-whores using comments as their new way to cheat.

Comment: Waffles never contribute to anything.