# Why search doesn't show proper relevant posts (which I can see as suggestion when trying to write a question)

Tags: discussion, bug, search

This happened many times with me. Just as an example, I was searching a post with keyword "Can upvotes of comments be rewarded with points", to check if any questions already exists with this topic. This is the result page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Can+upvotes+of+comments+be+rewarded+with+points. Where you wont find any relevant post. But then when I clicked on Ask Question and put the same in the Title area, I found some more relevant questions, one is this [Is it true that there is no points for posting an excellent comment?  Shouldn't adding excellent comments be somehow rewarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68968/311166), which matches with my view and this [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/311166) is the same question which I had in mind.

So, is there any valid reason, why the relevant posts doesn't come in the search results which may come in the duplicate suggestions?