# Should users earn reputation points for great comments?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments)

Should you gain reputation points when someone marks your comment as a "great comment"? Currently no points are gained in that situation. I think great comments should be rewarded.

Comment: I wouldn't give rep to the peanut gallery. If it's so good it should be an answer.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I should make that an answer.

Comment: Yes.  (please upvote, need rep!)

Comment: @Josh It's very nicely recursive.

Comment: @JoshK: That's code-less recursion what you did there.

Comment: Comments are often a meta conversation of a question or answer; they themselves are not the question or answer. Good work on Chat and Meta do not lead to points on the main site, though solid effort does lead to a few badges. Comments already have their own badge (*Pundit*). (In contrast, edits can be worth points because they add to a question or answer.)

Comment: Can I comment on a **closed** question?

Answer (score 9):

No.  Comments are not meant to contain the meat of the site.  Rewarding them with reputation, especially since many are merely humorous, will only result in a glut of comments from people only interesting in the rep they might possibly get.

Further, once you start gaining rep, someone will eventually complain that they can't downvote comments, and since they give rep that's important, and it'll blow up from there. Suddenly we need more moderation on comments, and people are penalized for funny or lighthearted comments because they "matter" now.

Leave them be.

Comment: My comment here is a humble bow-of-respect to your great answer. Ignore this if u prefer ;) But yeah I can see people gaming the site if we give even 0.2 points to a comment.

Answer (score 8):

## No

Comments are inherently un-score-able. They can be funny, and off topic (which is great) but that doesn't necessarily make them on-topic for the question and worthy of any reward. If the comment was so great make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To be fair, rep-on-votes really works if you can vote both ways (up AND down). I don't think there's any plan nor need to add downvoting to comments.