# Should comment upvotes reward reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments)

Sometimes, comments to answers can add useful insight that helps improve an answer to a question. However, comment upvotes currently do not earn the commenter any reputation. Should this perhaps be changed, such that comment upvotes earn the commenter a small amount of reputation? (Say, +1.)

Comment: @Arjan: Good points made over there. Also, the Pundit badge does kinda-sorta capture the intent of my suggestion, if only in a different way. Suggesting to close this question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, as more often than not comments just ask for thing (i.e. more code) in the question that a few people want too, so it gets up voted.

No one should get rep for asking for the obvious, also people who post funny comments tend to get a lot of up votes, I don't think the rep system should be polluted by this. It is first and foremost a professional network so we would be de-valuing the rep system if such a thing was implemented.

Comment: It seems like there should be reputation rewards for great comments. A comment with 100+ upvotes contributes to the community and should therefore be rewarded.  Even if it's something dumb like +1 reputation points for every comment with 100 upvotes; it's at least a gesture.  Maybe 25=>1; 50=>5; 100=>25 ?  

Upvote this comment if you agree :-)

Comment: @snekse And downvote the comment if you disagree?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, good question.  But what's being suggested is only a minor reputation boost for extremely valued comments.  You might not find it so valuable, and thus not upvote it, but it seems unlikely that a comment would get 100 upvotes and there nevertheless be a significant number of people who think the comment is detrimental.  (Hmm, then again, if the comment is just a joke that a lot of people like, it could easily deserve downvotes as well.)

Comment: @snekse, I'm mentally downvoting your comment because I disagree.