# Why hasn't my daily reputation score updated after my comments were upvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, comments, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Yesterday, I wrote two comments that got upvotes, but these don't show on the daily reputation score section. Was there any issue yesterday? Does it take time to update? Or am I missing something about how reputation works with comments?

Comment: Comments are not [listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/1438) as adding or subtracting from reputation.

Comment: I realize this isn't a feature request to allow comment votes to affect reputation. But if you *are* interested in that, you can start here: [Reputation for comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296) The topic has been broached and rejected numerous times; see the "Related" questions sidebar on the linked question.

Comment: [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/140505) and [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/140505)

Comment: @alfasin -- please do not make an update like that to your OP. that is not the way SE works...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA not sure I understood your comment about how SE works - what's wrong with updating the question ? by the way, thanks for the editing.

Comment: @CodyGray That's am interesting question and I'm totally fine with not counting comments' reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You receive no reputation for commenting on the site. Commenting works like *Whose Line is it Anyway?*, the points are all arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get reputation for comments. You only earn reputation for questions and answers.

The votes only matter when there are so many comments that the entire list is initially collapsed. In that case, the highest-rated comments are the ones that are shown.

Comment: The second sentence isn't [strictly true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/1438). ;-)

Comment: @Jon: Blah. Bounties are just a special case of answers, and suggested edits don't count as "posting" something on the site—they're not original creations, or at least they *shouldn't* be! Anyway, yes, thanks for the canonical reference.

Comment: I was thinking of account associations, for what it's worth.

Comment: @JonEricson - I was thinking accepted edits :)

Answer (score 1):

Comment votes **DO NOT** add to your reputation at all.