# Why don't useful comments reward reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments)

I have made many useful comments. However, it seems that a useful comment does not reward reputation. Why?

What is the role of useful comments?

Comment: Comments are of secondary importance. They help to clarify a question or answer. They are not generally considered as something for which you should gain rep. They might also be deleted at any time (more so than questions or answers).

Comment: Besides, comments cannot be voted down, so your perception of usefulness is skewed.

Comment: @Bart : for sure !

Comment: I don't see why this is a negative three question. Personally, I agree with the current comment setup, but it is not wrong or against the idea of meta to ask why.

Answer (score 8):

In nine out of ten cases, comments should help improving the question or answer at hand.

Once it served it purpose, the comment should get deleted. For example, a request for clarification becomes noise once the question has been edited to fulfill the request.

Reputation simply cannot be combined with the ephemeral nature of comments.

Comment: yes but sometines the answer is in the comment (a link, 2 or 3 words that can not be an anwser).

Comment: Rather than just posting a link, it's always preferable to post the relevant parts in an answer. If a question can be answered writing no more than three words, it should get closed as *not a real question*.

Comment: @Cybermaxs Then make it into a good substantial answer if you can. And if not, you're simply out of luck.