# Why doesn't SO award points for useful comments?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, comments

Why doesn't SO give a point for comments that get marked as useful?

As most serious users seem to realize, there are many situations where posting a comment is more appropriate than posting an answer. Yet, all the time I see answers posted that would have been more appropriate as comments - and it seems that the reason people do this is because they want to get points for their answer, whereas they can't get any for posting a useful comment.

A useful answer should certainly be awarded more than a useful comment, but is there a good reason why useful comments get nothing?

Comment: Comments are regarded to be low-priority. The up-voting is only there to filter out good comments from the others to display the most relevant ones. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, the focus is on questions and answers, not comments.

There are certainly several comments that are quite useful, but awarding reputation for comments would only encourage people to post more comments instead of answers. That's not really something we want, if someone has something truly useful to add, they should post an answer. And if what they have to add doesn't stand as an answer, they should either post it as a comment (and get no reputation for it) or not post it at all.

It's true that sometimes people post comments as answers, and they might get an upvote or two for it. However, eventually those non answers will be removed, and so will any reputation gain.

Comment: I don't know, Q&A&C has a nice ring to it. The mascot could be a duck. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You get shiny badges! What more would you want?

- [Commentator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator)
- [Pundit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit)