# If a question is tagged with status-declined because it was declined then it gets accepted will the tag change?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

If a question is tagged with status-declined tag (See image below) because it was declined by mgmt then it gets planned (status-planned tag) and completed  (status-completed tag), will the tag change accordingly?

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/reputation-for-comments) was tagged status-declined:

[image: Status-Declined Question]

Comment: @psubsee2003 I edited this question for clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specific question you referenced has an accepted answer but that means nothing.  It just means the original poster of that question picked an answer that he thought answered his question best.  The status tag tells you want the status of the question is.  If the status of the feature changes, then the tag *should* be updated.

However, if you encounter a question that has a status flag that does not seem to jive with a feature of the site, then feel free to flag the question.  It is possible that a status flag was applied incorrectly or was forgetten when the feature was implemented (or removed).

---

Ultimately decisions to implement features (or not) rest with the employees of Stack Exchange, Inc. Votes and accepted answers don't really mean much, but they do help guide them into what features might be desired by the community.

But just because there is a status flag doesn't mean it is set it stone, something could change in the future.  Features have been implemented after being declined, but there is usually some sort of notification.