# What's a good strategy for changing a status-declined question into a status-planned question?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange

What's a good strategy for changing a question tagged with *feature-request* and *status-declined* into a question tagged with *status-planned*.

Comment: If it is the question you referenced in your [previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206829/if-a-question-is-tagged-with-status-declined-because-it-was-declined-then-it-get), then never.  But in general, a good answer explaining why the feature can be beneficial would be best or what [Martijn said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/206834/182513)

Comment: Sacrifice three black chickens and a goat/

Comment: @Rosinante Now I have many more questions. I don't think this solution would be helpful.

Comment: 1) Have (or acquire) upwards of 28 Million Dollars
2) Buy Stack Overflow from the [VC firms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/announcing-our-series-a/) that (probably) currently hold the majority of the company
3) Go to their [hexagonal New York offices](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange) 
4) Call a meeting
5) Fire everyone who could stand in your way (advisory boards and such) 6) Give specific orders to implement that feature RIGHT F███ING NOW 7) 6-8 weeks later, watch the new feature unfold!

Comment: @probably Pekka Now I have many more questions. I don't think this solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You would have to come up with a *new* proposal that addresses the concerns raised against the old declined proposal.

This may well be an uphill battle however, so choose your proposal and arguments wisely.

If you build a better mousetrap and can tell the world, the developers will beat a path to your door.

Comment: I've done that before with other people's questions, but they have all been marked as duplicates of the original proposals with no action taken.

Comment: @gparyani: Did your question link to the previous discussion and show why your new question was covering new ground and addressed the objections raised before? I did say that the approach is an uphill battle, you need to be *thorough* for it to work.